# Excepción al comunicarme con un servicio web en Localhost: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake

Tags: java, ssl, localhost

Estoy depurando un servicio web REST en Netbeans 11.1 corriendo sobre jdk 8_u231 x64 (Windows 10).
Cuando lo depuro con glassfish 5 obtengo la siguiente excepcion al consumirlo desde una aplicación java  (también en depuración en Netbeans) y Soap UI 5.5.0:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection
> during handshake

El stack trace es el siguiente:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection
> during handshake java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:994)
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
> sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
> sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
> sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1570)
> sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1498)
> java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
> sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:352)

Cuando cambio el servidor a Tomcat 8.5 obtengo esta excepción:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext
> connection?
> sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(InputRecord.java:710)
> sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:527)
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:975)
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
> sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
> sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
> sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1570)
> sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1498)
> java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
> sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:352)

Intenté lo que dicen aquí https://stackoverflow.com/q/21245796/111110, y aquí https://stackoverflow.com/q/55119650/111110 y aquí https://stackoverflow.com/q/28908835/111110 sin éxito. Intenté cambiar la dirección de https://localhost:8080/ a http://localhost:8080/ y entonces obtengo el error http 404.
Obtengo los mismos resultados desde mi aplicación de java y Soap UI.
No tengo proxy, y el problema persiste cuando desactivo mi firewall (java tiene acceso completo a mi red).

**Edit:**
No he hecho configuraciones de certificados digitales.

En el caso de Tomcat, encontré esto en el log de Catalina:

> 29-Sep-2020 10:47:32.276 INFORMACIÓN [http-nio-8080-exec-12]
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service Error analizando
> cabecera de requerimiento HTTP  Note: further occurrences of HTTP
> request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Se encontró un carácter inválido
> en el nombre del método. Los nombres de métodos HTTP deben ser tokens
> at
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:432)
> at
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:502)
> at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
> at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:818)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1627)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Cómo están configurados en cada caso? El server.xml de tomcat y la config de netbeans? Estás montando un certificado autofirmado o cómo estás montando https? Qué ves en los logs de tomcat cuando pruebas

Answer (score 0):

Este error es porque intentas acceder por HTTPS a un puerto que acepta comunicación HTTP. El servidor no entiende el galimatías que le estas pasando (toda la información para estableer la conexión HTTPS) y cierra la conexión.

> Intenté cambiar la dirección de https://localhost:8080/ a http://localhost:8080/ y entonces obtengo el error http 404.

Aquí has solucionado el problema arriba indicado. Al cambiar el protocolo a HTTP, **se establece la conexión** y se procesa tu petición. Sin embargo, estás pidiendo un recurso que no existe y el servidor te devuelve el 404 Not Found. No estás poniendo bien la ruta del API REST.

En resumen:

- Usa el protocolo adecuado al puerto. Normalemente un puerto 80 o 8080 será HTTP, 443 o 8443 HTTPS. No recuerdo si tomcat tiene configurado por defecto el puerto 8443, basta con que hagas https://localhost:8443 en tu navegador y veas si te sale algo.
- Para el puerto HTTPS necesitas que tu cliente acepte el certificado del servidor. Por defecto tomcat usará un certificado autofirmado que tu cliente no reconocerá, deberás importarlo en el keystore.
- Revisa la configuració de tu API REST para averiguar la ruta correcta.

Conviene tratar esto como dos problemas distintos:

- Contactar a tu API REST usando HTTP.
- Configurar el servidor y tu cliente para usar una conexión HTTPS.

Una vez que sabes usar el API REST con HTTP, y has configurado la conexión HTTPS, usar el API REST sobre HTTPS es automático.